# Closing a PDF file, generated when text is updated - Tkinter

Tags: python, pdf, tkinter

So I have a function which generates a pdf file from a latex file in Tkinter -  but only when a button is clicked.
What I am trying to do now is write a function which updates the pdf file every few seconds, so that the user can see how what they have written so far looks like. What I do is run the function which generates the pdf every few seconds and another function, which is supposed to close the file after a few seconds - but I seem to have a problem with closing the pdf files - hence I need to do it manually, otherwise the updated version of the pdf does not appear on the screen.
Here is the code I have used:

```
 def generate_pdf(self):
    global mainName
    global pdfDirectory
    name=self.getName(self.fl)
    f = open('%s.tex'%name,'w')
    tex = self.txt.get(1.0,"end-1c")
    f.write(tex)
    f.close()
    proc=subprocess.Popen(['pdflatex','-output-directory', pdfDirectory,'%s.tex'%name])
    proc.communicate()
    self.open_file(name)
    self.master.after(20000,self.generate_pdf)
    self.close_file(name)

def open_file(self,filename):
    if sys.platform == "win32":
        os.startfile('%s.pdf'%filename)
        #os.unlink('%s.tex'%filename)
        os.unlink('%s.log'%filename)
        os.unlink('%s.aux'%filename)
    else:
        opener ="open" if sys.platform == "darwin" else "xdg-open"
        subprocess.call([opener, '%s.pdf'%filename])    

def close_file(self,filename):
    if sys.platform == "win32":
        os.close('%s.pdf'%filename)    

    else:
        closer ="close" if sys.platform == "darwin" else "xdg-close"
        subprocess.call([closer, '%s.pdf'%filename])    
    self.master.after(29000,self.close_file)
```

The error I get when running it in Windows is:

```
os.close('%s.pdf'%filename)
TypeError: an integer is required
```

The error I get when running it in Linux is:

```
File "interface_updated_Linux.py", line 716, in generate_pdf
    self.close_file(name)
  File "interface_updated_Linux.py", line 734, in close_file
    subprocess.call([closer, '%s.pdf'%filename])
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 478, in call
    p = Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 642, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 1238, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1):

From [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.close):

> `os.close(fd)`
>
> Close **file descriptor** `fd`.
>
> Availability: Unix, Windows.
>
> Note This function is intended for low-level I/O and **must be applied**
>   **to a file descriptor as returned by `os.open()` or `pipe()`**. To close a
>   “file object” returned by the built-in function `open()` or by `popen()`
>   or `fdopen()`, use its `close()` method.

You're trying to apply it to a string here.

You should figure out how to pass around the file descriptor among the methods in your class. This might be a little bit more complicated in the case where you're using `subprocess` to open/close files, but in general you're gonna need a (file handle/file descriptor/process ID) to close a file. Simply using the name is not sufficient since for example you could have two handles to the same file open, how would it know which one to close?